# Mongo aggregation performance

Tags: mongodb, performance, aggregation-framework

I am new to mongo and below query performs really slow with record set over 2 Million records

**Query**

```html
 db.testCollection.aggregate({
     $match: {
         active: {
             $ne: false
         }
     }
 }, {
     $group: {
         _id: {
             productName: "$productName",
             model: "$model",
             version: "$version",
             uid: "$uid"
         },
         total: {
             $sum: 1
         }
     }
 }, {
     $project: {
         total: 1,
         model: "$_id.model",
         version: "$_id.version",
         uid: "$_id.uid",
         productName: "$_id.productName"
     }
 }, {
     $sort: {
         model: 1
     }
 })
```

explain()

```
{
"stages" : [
    {
        "$cursor" : {
            "query" : {
                "active" : {
                    "$ne" : false
                }
            },
            "fields" : {
                "version" : 1,
                "productName" : 1,
                "model" : 1,
                "uid" : 1,
                "_id" : 0
            },
            "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "fms2.device",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                    "$nor" : [
                        {
                            "active" : {
                                "$eq" : false
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "active" : 1
                        },
                        "indexName" : "active",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                            "active" : [ ]
                        },
                        "isUnique" : false,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "indexVersion" : 2,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "active" : [
                                "[MinKey, false)",
                                "(false, MaxKey]"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : {
                "productName" : "$productName",
                "model" : "$model",
                "version" : "$version",
                "uid" : "$uid"
            },
            "total" : {
                "$sum" : {
                    "$const" : 1
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project" : {
            "_id" : true,
            "total" : true,
            "model" : "$_id.model",
            "version" : "$_id.version",
            "uid" : "$_id.uid",
            "productName" : "$_id.productName"
        }
    },
    {
        "$sort" : {
            "sortKey" : {
                "model" : 1
            }
        }
    }
],
"ok" : 1
```

}

Is there a way to optimize this query more ? I had a look into https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/ as well but most of the stated suggestions are not applicable for this query.

Not sure if it matters, result of this aggregation ends up with only 20-30 records.

Comment: Does the query also run slow without aggregation? Do you have any indexes on the collection?

Comment: Below are the indexes details <br/> [{"v":2,"key":{"_id":1},"name":"_id_","ns":"dbName.test"},{"v":2,"key":{"version":1},"name":"version","ns":"dbName.test"},{"v":2,"key":{"uid":1},"name":"uid","ns":"dbName.test"},{"v":2,"key":{"model":1},"name":"model","ns":"dbName.test"},{"v":2,"key":{"productName":1},"name":"productName","ns":"dbName.test"},{"v":2,"key":{"active":1},"name":"active","ns":"dbName.test"}]

Comment: so you basically have an index for every field? That's not very performant I would say.

Comment: Yes, taking over an existing code base :) Should I go for compound index?

Comment: Just try to figure out first what's making the query slow, meaning isolate the issue.. remove all the indexes, try a simple query, then try with some aggregation.. This way you can identity the culprit and actually fix the problem.

Comment: I would suggest an compound index on    model, version, uid, productName

Comment: Thanks @jpgrassi .Will try it out

Comment: @Krishna Thanks! after adding compound index seeing some improvement but still query takes 8.5s from 11.5 s

Comment: @RamyaN Please post some data and your new index information. that will be helpful

Comment: Consider Index prefixes. More repeating data columns comes first and next less repeating data. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/#prefixes. Use allowdiskuse:true as option in your query. The response time greatly depends on your machines RAM availability and Cores available.